# Hover popup shows wrong/duplicate rep for week/month/etc in user profile page

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface, popups

I posted a similar question on [Meta.English.SE](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2545/bug-squash-request) before I realized the problem extended to other sites as well.  I'll pick on SO for the images here, though I can repro this behavior in  any other site.  In the user page, in the [voters](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=voters) or [editors](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=editors) tabs, in any view except *all*, hovering over the rep of any user brings up a popup such as the following:

[image]

And when the user's rep is less than 10000, it appears like this:

[image]

Not sure why, but the rep tab has no problems in any view:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks, this will be fixed in the next build.