# Should design/layout/css issues be brought up here or on per-site metas?

Tags: discussion, meta, per-site-meta

In the case of a bug that appears to be due to a CSS layout on a StackExchange site, should the issue be raised on that site's meta, or on Meta? I know there is a lot of consistency across the network, but that some issues can still be site-specific.

Example (from [English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/badges/38/favorite-question)):
[image]

The last question title runs off the page and the end (along with the user who asked it) are not visible. Looking at the same page here on Meta, I noticed some long question names but no issues.

Should issues like this be brought up on the individual site's meta or here on Meta, or does it depend on whether it appears to be a multi-site issue?

Related: [There is an issue displaying long question titles on the "Favorite Question" tag page on EL&U](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126323/167443).

Another example:
This issue was brought up on [two](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126277/167443) [metas](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2545/11762).

Comment: I believe that site-specific design issues should always be brought up on the per-site meta as [meta-tag:bug] [meta-tag:design], but I don't know if two or more sites have similar sorts of issues if that qualifies as a network-wide problem or not. I'm leaning towards no, but I'm not sure what [Jin](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/147574/jin) wants.

Comment: I guess a more direct version of my question would be with all the consistency (general layout, functionality) across the network, how much design is actually site-specific?

Comment: Matthew's answer below is spot on, just wanted to add that ultimately, it doesn't matter where the bug is reported.  It just needs to be reported.  We do not expect every user to be familiar enough with the network to be able to evaluate where a meta post belongs.  That's on us, not you.

Comment: @RebeccaChernoff Ok, thanks. That's about what I expected. I was just wondering what the preferred way of going about it is (I actually just posted the example issue as a bug on EL&U meta)

Comment: Related - http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/89232

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- You can always bring up any issue on the site you noticed it on.
- This site (MSO) is only for SO-specific or multi-site issues.
- Don't create more than one post about the same issue.  The SE folk check the individual site metas so you don't need to post on one of them and then here.

I'd say that if you know it's a multi-site issue then you should post here, but again it's fine to post on an affected site.  Once MSO is split into "new SO-specific MSO" and MSE I think the former may be more strongly encouraged, assuming that happens.

If you want to see whether something is site-specific, just check other sites!  If you can't find an obvious and non-obtrusive way to test on another site then just post on the site where you did see the bug.

Comment: Yes, and remember that the developers monitoring the per-site metas can migrate questions here if they are actually network-wide problems. If it looks to be a problem with the layout of a particular site, there's no reason not to post the question the per-site meta.

Comment: Great answer, sir.

Comment: That last part covers exactly what I was looking for (can't reproduce on other sites - doesn't necessarily mean it doesn't exist there, just might not be visible at the time).

Comment: Doesn't that make it harder to find [potential duplicate issues](http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/a/716/162) across the network?

Comment: @Troyen Yes. The SE folk are the ones best equipped to deal with bug dupes and they're also the ones who have a presence on every meta, so it's not *too* bad ... though I can't say I envy them that.