# Should questions about SE site features be moved from all other metas to SO meta?

Tags: discussion, per-site-meta

I wonder if questions about a feature that any SE site has on other metas belong on the StackOverflow meta.

For example, this question here:
[How to follow (or favourite) particular users?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4100/how-to-follow-or-favourite-particular-users)

It's asking about following a user, which applies to all other SE sites. Does this mean it's off-topic on English and Usage meta and should be moved to StackOverflow meta?

Comment: This site functions as both the meta for questions specific to just SO, and also as the SE wide meta site, as is stated in the "about" page.

Comment: @Servy Is that a "Yes"?

Comment: @Servy I'm not sure you understood the issue here

Comment: See also: [Should design/layout/css issues be brought up here or on per-site metas?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126323)

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Request for Official Clarification on Proper Location of Meta Questions for SE 2.0 Sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/55513)

Comment: That's an old question @AlEverett, and one that doesn't answer this.

Comment: Related: [The future of meta.stackoverflow and meta.stackexchange](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124015/the-future-of-meta-stackoverflow-and-meta-stackexchange)

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards oh yes, definitely that one! Can I mark my own question as duplicate? :p