# The bug dies hard

Tags: bug, status-completed, popups

I recently posted about a [popup bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126277/164012) which has mostly been squashed in this build, but it's still waving its legs around on the floor.

In the rep tab, in the quarter or year view, anyone who has earned more than 10K rep this year so far has a popup which looks like this:

[image]

Anyone with less than 10K rep this year/quarter has no problem.

Could someone put this bug out of its misery?

Comment: in b4 the "Actually, for Jon Skeet, that number is correct" comments.

Comment: Oops, we showed Skeet's *real* rep, our bad.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The excess number has been led outside by our security personnel and asked to never return to the premises. The restraining order will be in force with the next build.

Comment: Letting it live in exile and just getting a restraining order? You are _begging_ for a sequel.